# Any way to add custom type modifiers to either c# or c++?

Tags: c#, c++, coding-efficiency

I want to be able to use this syntax here:

```
public enclosed int num = {0, 5, 10};
```

this code would clamp the int num from 0 to 10, with a starting value of 5.

you could make a class that handles this, but it would be a lot of extra effort for a sort of convoluted solution, and I'm wondering if there is a way to somehow to do it just in a variable declaration, sort of like declaring an unsigned int, I want to be able to declare an enclosed int.

Comment: Probably not for c++, and absolutely not for c#.

Comment: Any effort you put into implementing the class has to go into the modifier as well. Bounded integer types are a thing if you want to look for a library.

Comment: For both this question and your previous one: C# is not customizable to any significant degree. The syntax just is what it is.

Comment: Maybe a macro would be helpful here (c++)

Comment: Make that "absolutely not" for C++, too.

Comment: You can't even do that with a C# enum.  If you create an enum with 5 members (corresponding to integers 0-4), you can cast int 42 to that type and the compiler stays happy.  There are languages that allow you to restrict types like that, but I don't know of any C-derived languages that do.  In C#, value types always default to a zero-ish value; you can't have a "starting value of 5"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is exactly what classes and structs are for, so that you can create your own types with these sorts of behaviors. But these are compiled languages, so the syntax is fixed. In C++ you might be able to do something using macros, but that's a preprocessor thing.

Comment: Highly unlikely in C++ with macros as well. Definitively not with the specific shown syntax. Also a macro solution, if at all, would at best only be hiding the class definition behind the macro. Rather pointless.

Comment: But I don't understand what rigid syntax has to do with the language being compiled.

Comment: Many interpreted and scripting languages support metaprogramming which would allow you to define your own syntax because you can control how code is interpreted at execution time. That's all I was getting at with that comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got pretty close :P

```
public class enclosed<T> {
    private T min {get;}
    private T max {get;}
    private T val {get;}
    
    public enclosed(T min, T val, T max)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
public enclosed<int> num = new(0, 5, 10);
```

vs

```
public enclosed int num = {0, 5, 10};
```

Comment: That actually looks great, all you have to do now is set up operator overloading for all the different operators so that you can use it like a built in type!